# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. java.lang.NullPointerException: Firestore component is not present

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase on Android and I'm trying to instantiate Firestore by: 
`FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` 
but I'm getting Null Pointer Exception

p.s.: If I don't instantiante FirebaseApp 
`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)), I get the error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

[EDITED]

APP build.gradle:

https://pastebin.com/k7e0Vzy4

PROJECT build.gradle:

https://pastebin.com/hMjwpAK9

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the content of your both `build.gradle` files.

Comment: I attached the link to build.gradle files

Comment: Your dependencies are fine. Please also add a snippet from your code where you instantiate the FirebaseFirestore object.

Comment: LoginActivity.java: https://pastebin.com/QDUujTVC

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting the NPE?

Comment: when I call `rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`

Comment: Got the same problem. Only reproducing on one phone, but fine for another.
Crashing right on lines:
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

Answer (score 0):

initializeApp with Firebase before getting instance

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
```